# May i know the reason why i am unable to send image by using following code(as MMS)

Tags: android, mms

i am trying to implement MMS application to send a pic/image.For that i have written below code.But after press ok message is sending like SMS not like MMS(Image is not attaching).
Please help me wheter the following code is correct or not.

```
try {        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/pictures/kc.jpg");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.putExtra("address",etnum.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("sms_body",etmsg.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,"file:/"+uri);
            i.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,"file:/"+uri); will resolve to `file:/file://mnt/sdcard/pictures/kc.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove "file:/" from EXTRA_STREAM, just i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
2. Change setType to i.setType("image/*");